# How do I display local image with discord.js message embed?

Tags: discord.js

I'm working on semi-gacha bot command where you can pull characters and so on. I want to display the characters image after the user pulls and here is where I get stuck, it just doesn't display anything and I found what looked like the answer on here, but it didn't help, as I would get the same result and I don't get any errors, so I don't know what exactly is wrong. I have tried printing out the result of MessageAttachment first:

```
const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment('./chars/1.Jakku.png', '1.Jakku.png');
console.log(attachment);
```

and I get: `undefined`, anybody has any ideas of what am I doing wrong? And yes, I have discord.js library imported.
Relevant part of the code:

```
                    collector.on('collect', reaction => {
                        //new embd
                        const newEmbd = new Discord.MessageEmbed();

                        // gacha logic
                        if (reaction.emoji.name === '✅') {  
                            const values = Object.values(chars);
                            const randomChar = values[parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random()*values.length))];

                            const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment('./chars/1.Jakku.png', '1.Jakku.png');
                            const charData = randomChar.split('.');

                            newEmbd
                                .setTitle(`You pulled: ${charData[1]}!`)
                                .setColor('YELLOW')
                                .attachFiles(attachment)
                                .setImage(`attachment://1.Jakku.png`);
                            embdReact.edit(newEmbd);
                            pulled = true;
                        } else if (reaction.emoji.name === '❌') {
                            newEmbd
                                .setTitle('Time for gacha!')
                                .setColor('YELLOW')
                                .addFields(
                                    { name: 'Result:', value: 'You decided against pulling' }
                                );
                            embdReact.edit(newEmbd);
                        };
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the correct syntax for attaching files as per [this guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#using-the-richembedmessageembed-constructor)

```js
const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Some title')
    .attachFiles(['./chars/1.Jakku.png'])

message.channel.send(exampleEmbed);
```

Comment: still doesn't work, unless I'm still misunderstanding something

Comment: none, that is what is making it hard to understand

Comment: hmmm, is it simply not sending?

Comment: embed gets sent but only the title, image stays as undefined

Comment: ohh, youre trying to add a thumbnail? -  I will run this on my bot and try and find a solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229408/discussion-between-joe-moore-and-wowy).